# How to submit form using a .NET Console application

Tags: c#, php, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to fill and submit form using Console application? Lets say the http://mysite/connection.php website has the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="connection.php">
  <input placeholder="User Name" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
  <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Connection" />
</form>
```

How can I use C#/VB.NET to submit this form using a Console application?

Comment: Look at `WebClient`, `HttpClient` or `WebRequest`

Comment: Just send a POST request to that URL using System.Net.Http.HttpClient.

Comment: Oh my god I just got beaten to a comment by Jon Skeet (faint)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WebRequest` to post data in .NET

> **Your code will be like this**

```
WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create('http://mysite/connection.php');
myReq.Method = "POST";
myReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
myReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
/* And your further code goes here */
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question since there was no need to send JSON but form data

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebClient for this as follows:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("username", username);
nvc.Add("password", pwd);
byte[] responseArray = wc.UploadValues(url,"POST",nvc);
```

More detail can be found at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900ted1f.aspx